# Slang words which came into English from other languages?

Tags: slang

Are there such modern slang words in British or American versions of the English language which came from other foreign languages?

Answer (score 2):

Lots:  Slang tends to be very local to particular groups, so where languages interact you get slang.

Any summary will miss out more words than it includes, however you get Spanish phrases, like "Hasta la vista" in American English.

On the other hand you have borrowing from Hindi such as "pukka" (meaning "just right") in Southern English slang. There are quite a few slang terms from Romani (the language of the Roma "gypsies") like "cushty" and "wonga".